# Sandbox app in purchase show different price iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I configured the app in-app-purchase for the price in apple developer account 19.99 EURO [image]

But in sandbox it shows the price 21.99 EURO, I found out 6 years ago there were similar bug reported by others, so any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got email from apple that they confirm this is a bug in sandbox environment. in production seems it works.

Comment: In any case please keep in mind that tier values can change at any time.

Comment: So this means that the apple can show in production environment wrong price?

Comment: It means that the absolute value of the price shown is volatile. It is the tier that remains constant (unless you change it of course). So the number shown is not really very important.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem but in subscription 
In my case, on app store connect i had a starting price and the change price that i added after that.
For sandbox
In the product, i see the changed price but once i trigger a purchase i see the starting price in the app store action sheet.

It is a bug from apple side.

Comment: This response would have been better submitted as a comment and not an answer.The content is fine but where it lands in the discussion is confusing for StackOverflow users in general.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced an issue that I changed my app subscription price from ,$0.99 to $4.99 I submitted build for review and its got rejected 3 times because price at front end was different, and when we were clicking on payment sandbox price was different we were directly fetching price from App store, I tried to find solution online and also connected store app review team but its didn't work, at the end I find solution by my own ,if you're facing similar issue here is step to solve:
Go to apple developer account, and click on subscription.
Go to subscription group and click on your subscription product
Click on pricing , you'll see two pricing
Current price , and price with date which will be your change price
If you're change price date and current date same mean your price is change
So what you need to do just click on current price
Then click on edit pricing , select all countries and you'll see current price and change price comparison click on done now check in app you're sandbox price will be changed.
If your are facing same issue or any question feel free to ask